# How to provide two-factor authentication in Kubuntu without a phone

Tags: two-factor-authentication

Is it possible to use two-factor authentication on a Linux laptop running Kubuntu 18.04 without using a phone at all?  If so, how?

I'm able to authenticate on my phone without any particular difficulty.  But when I log into Coinbase under Kubuntu, I'm asked for a 2-step verification code.  Running Authenticator under Kubuntu, I'm asked for a provider (presumably Coinbase), an account name (presumably my account name at Coinbase), and a 2FA token.  It seems that both Authenticator and Coinbase are asking for codes, and neither of them are providing codes.  It's like trying to connect a male plug to another male plug.

I would guess that I'm making a major conceptual error -- but what?

Comment: FYI: Kubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) or Ubuntu Kylin have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Kubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.

Comment: How do you intend to use 2 factor authentication?  At login, on Google or Amazon's web site etc?  Yubikey gives you several choices for 2fa, a fidokey is cheaper.

Comment: I need 2FA in order to log onto the Coinbase website.  When I first set up my account there, 2FA wasn't required.

Comment: EarIier, I mistakenly said I was running Kubuntu 16.04.  In fact, I'm running Kubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Coinbase supports Yubikey.  From https://help.coinbase.com/en/coinbase/getting-started/authentication-and-verification/2-factor-authentication-2fa-faq :

> Coinbase supports all WebAuthN / Fido2 standard security keys. An
> option for a security key is Yubico's yubikey.

See [Using security keys](https://help.coinbase.com/en/coinbase/managing-my-account/identity-verification/using-and-managing-security-keys)

The Yubikey plugs into a USB port, emulates a keyboard, and produces a security code when touched. Should work with Kubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Yubikey is a hardware device, so it's probably only worth using for critical and valuable accounts.  In this case I can always use my phone if need be.  I was hoping there was a lightweight way to do this in Kubuntu without involving anything else.  Using the website and the Kubuntu version of Authenticator would be ideal -- if I could get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a password manager like [KeePassXC](https://keepassxc.org/) that has a built-in 2FA function to create TOTP or "Time-Based One-Time Passwords". It allows you to store the secret you get from the service you set it up for, and then create a 2FA code whenever you need it, just like a Yubikey. The only difference is the secrets are stored on your PC (or whereever) in your password manager database, not on a hardware key. It's cheaper, but depending on your threat model may be less secure.

You only need to be sure the 2FA code you need is compatible - some sites use their own proprietary stuff. Anything that works with "Google Authenticator" is usually fine. Coinbase seems to do so.